# Vue 3 with Composition API different object structure for getting context/globalProperties with Vue-CLI 4 in dev build or production build?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-cli, vue-composition-api

Why is the object structure from the `getCurrentInstance()` result with the Composition API different in development or production build?

---

I use the following pattern for adding globals to my Vue instance:

```js
    export default {
      install(app) {
        const _projectFile = new ProjectFile(app);
    
        //* This will help for accessing the store in other files (plugins)
        app.config.globalProperties.$projectProperties = _projectFile;
    
        //* This will expose the store in components with this.$store
        app.provide('$projectProperties', _projectFile);
      }
    };
```

---

I am initiating this in my `main.js`, with a bunch of other stuff (**this all works fine**).

```js
    import App from './App.vue'; // Main Vue component
    const app = createApp(App)
    .use(projectProperties);
    app.mount('#app');
```

---

**The actual weirdness starts here.**. When trying to access my globalProperties from the `setup()` (Compostion API) in `./App.vue`. I get a different object structure for `getCurrentInstance()` when running:

1. `vue-cli-service serve` (development)
2. `vue-cli-service build` (production)

---

`./App.vue`

```js
  setup() {
    const _instance = getCurrentInstance();

    onMounted(async function() {
      // This one is only valid from vue-cli-service serve
      const { $store, $router, $projectProperties } = _instance.ctx;

      // This will work for both vue-cli-service serve & build
      const { $store, $router, $projectProperties } = _instance.appContext.app.config.globalProperties;

      // Other non relevant code down here

    });
  },
```

So this will not work in my production build:
`const { $store, $router, $projectProperties } = _instance.ctx;`

**I don't get why the `getCurrentInstance().ctx` points towards the `globalProperties` object with `cli-service serve` but does not contain the globalProperties in the `cli-service build`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out [`ctx` is intended for development mode only](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/4549e65/packages/runtime-core/src/component.ts#L487). `ctx` exposes the global properties for [easier console inspection](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/4549e65baea54bfd10116241a6a5eba91ec3f632/packages/runtime-core/src/componentPublicInstance.ts#L461-L464).

If you need the global properties in both development and production modes, you need to stick with `_instance.appContext.app.config.globalProperties`.